# ¿Cómo mostrar empleados con sueldos mayores a $1000? En C o C++

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con mi código. Quiero mostrar los empleados con sueldos mayores a 1000 dólares en la función `void MostrarDatosMmil();`. Lo he intentado de esta forma y no me muestra nada. El resto de funciones funcionan correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sueld 1000

//Estructura empleados
struct empleados 
{
    char nombre[30];
    char apellido[30];
    int edad;
    float sueldo;
    char genero [15];
};
    
empleados *Cantidad = new empleados[2000];    //Cantidad máxima de personas

// Funciones
void IngresarDatos();
void MostrarDatos();
void MostrarDatosMmil();

// Funcion principal
int i = 0;
int main()
{
    int opc;
    do { 
        printf("\t\tBienvenido a la base de datis de empleados\n");
        printf("\n1. Ingresar datos de los empleados\n");
        printf("2. Mostrar datos de los empleados\n");
        printf("3. Mostrar empleados con sueldo superior a 1000\n");
        printf(". Salir\n");
        printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d",&opc);

        switch (opc)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                IngresarDatos();
                getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                MostrarDatos();
                getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                MostrarDatosMmil();
                getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
        }

    } while (opc != 4);

    return 0;
}
    
void IngresarDatos()
{
    int numempl;
    int repite = 0;
    printf("Seleccione la cantidad de empleados a ingresar: ");
    scanf("%d", &numempl);
    do
    {
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s",&Cantidad[i].nombre);
        printf("Ingrese el apellido del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s",&Cantidad[i].apellido);
        printf("Ingrese el edad del empleado: ");
        scanf("%d",&Cantidad[i].edad);
        printf("Ingrese el sueldo del empleado: ");
        scanf("%f",&Cantidad[i].sueldo);
        printf("Ingrese el genero del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s",&Cantidad[i].genero);
        i++;
        repite++;   
    } while (repite != numempl);
}
   
void MostrarDatos()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("\n\nNombre: %s         \nApellido: %s         \nEdad: %d          \nSueldo: %0.2f         \nGenero: %s",
            Cantidad[j].nombre, Cantidad[j].apellido, Cantidad[j].edad, Cantidad[j].sueldo, Cantidad[j].genero);
    }
}

void MostrarDatosMmil()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
    {
        if (Cantidad[i].sueldo > sueld)
        {
            printf("\n\nNombre: %s         \nApellido: %s         \nEdad: %d          \nSueldo: %0.2f         \nGenero: %s",
                Cantidad[k].nombre, Cantidad[k].apellido, Cantidad[k].edad, Cantidad[k].sueldo, Cantidad[k].genero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explica que has intentado por favor

Comment: ¿Seguro que el código es [tag:c++]?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster a pesar de usar bibliotecas de C, utiliza un `new`, por lo que entiendo que sí es C++ y que lo compilará como C++.

Comment: A pesar de no usar ni una cabecera de C++, a pesar de interactuar con el usuario con `printf` y `scanf`, a pesar de no usar ni un paradigma de C++, usa `new` sin usar `delete`... así que como mucho será C+ û_û

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es en la función `MostarDatosMmil`, ya que la llamada a `printf` está bien, pero la comprobación no.

```
void MostrarDatosMmil()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)    // Esto está bien
    {
        if (Cantidad[i].sueldo > sueld)    // Esto está mal
        {
            printf("\n\nNombre: %s         \nApellido: %s         \nEdad: %d          \nSueldo: %0.2f         \nGenero: %s",
                Cantidad[k].nombre, Cantidad[k].apellido, Cantidad[k].edad, Cantidad[k].sueldo, Cantidad[k].genero);
        }
    }
}
```

Estás recorriendo desde el primer elemento (0) al último (i - 1), pero en todas las iteraciones compruebas si el elemento i (está después del último) tiene un sueldo inferior a 1000.

Esto va a tener un comportamiento indefinido, ya que las variables no se inicializan por defecto, y pueden contener cualquier valor, positivo, negativo o cero. Por lo que algunas veces te mostrará el empleado k y otras no.

En cualquier caso, va a ser incorrecto porque el hecho de mostrar el empleado k depende del empleado i, que todavía no se ha metido en la colección de empleados.

Es más, si llegas a llenar el vector de empleados, se intentará acceder al empleado 2001 y podrá saltar un fallo de segmento por intentar acceder a una zona que no se ha reservado.

La comprobación del `if` debería ser:

```
if (Cantidad[k].sueldo > sueld) ...
```

En cualquier caso, considera seguir las convenciones de C/C++ (etiquetas tu pregunta como C++ pero utilizas bibliotecas de C, y no usas ninguna característica de C++, salvo el `new empleados[2000]`): escribir el **nombre de funciones y variables empezando con minúscula** (*lower camel case* por ejemplo), y los `#define ALGO` en mayúscula (sin empezar por guiones, ya que estos tienen un uso reservado al compilador).

Además, te recomiendo que no declares una variable global llamada `i` porque su nombre no significa nada. Considera **refactorizarla como `numeroEmpleados`** por ejemplo, y poner nombres de variables completos y significativos.

Además, una variable de tipo `struct empleados` no va a contener muchos empleados, sino uno, por lo que te recomiendo poner el nombre en singular.

Para un mayor orden y corrección sería incluso mejor declarar otra estructura, que contenga la colección (vector) de empleados y el número de empleados insertados hasta el momento.

```
#define MAXIMO_NUMERO_EMPLEADOS 2000
#define SUELDO_MIL 1000

struct empleado
{
    char nombre[30];
    char apellido[30];
    int edad;
    float sueldo;
    char genero[15];
};

typedef struct empleado Empleado;

struct coleccionEmpleados
{
    Empleado empleados[MAXIMO_NUMERO_EMPLEADOS];
    unsigned numeroEmpleados;
    coleccionEmpleados() : numeroEmpleados(0) {}    // Constructor C++
};

typedef struct coleccionEmpleados ColeccionEmpleados;

ColeccionEmpleados coleccionEmpleados;    // coleccionEmpleados != struct coleccionEmpleados

...

void mostrarDatosMil()
{
    for (int empleado = 0; empleado < coleccionEmpleados.numeroEmpleados; empleado++)
    {
        if (coleccionEmpleados.empleados[empleado].sueldo > SUELDO_MIL) printf(...);
    }
}
```

Incluso puedes definir métodos dentro de los *structs* para trabajar con ellos de forma más cómoda y lógica. Por ejemplo:

```
#define OPCION_MOSTRAR_MIL 3

struct coleccionEmpleados
{
    Empleado empleados[MAXIMO_NUMERO_EMPLEADOS];
    unsigned numeroEmpleados;
    coleccionEmpleados() : numeroEmpleados(0) {}    // Constructor C++
    void mostrarEmpleadosMil()
    {
        for (unsigned empleado = 0; empleado < numeroEmpleados; empleado++) printf(...);
    }
};

typedef struct coleccionEmpleados ColeccionEmpleados;

ColeccionEmpleados coleccionEmpleados;    // Llamada implícita al constructor sin parámetros

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ...
    switch (opcion)
    {
        ...
        case OPCION_MOSTRAR_MIL:
            coleccionEmpleados.mostrarEmpleadosMil();
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Así no tendrías métodos libres que manejen estructuras, sino que las estructuras proveen métodos para manejarlas adecuadamente.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por tu amplia explicación amigo. Ya implementare todo lo que me indicaste. Gracias por tu tiempo otra vez